# Битрикс24 Смена стадии в сделке при наступлении определенной даты

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Менеджер заполняет поле-даты в сделке. Когда время сервера = поле-даты должно переходить на следующую стадию

Я так понимаю что делать нужно через триггер, сделал триггер на изменение поля по условию что поле-даты = {=System:Now}

не работает, подскажите как реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, решается с помощью робота, а не триггера 
Робот на смену стадии, время выполнения: Точное время = поле-даты